# SharePoint 2010 Navigation Menu Missing

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, master-pages

Apologies in advance, this may be long winded. I'm working on a SharePoint 2010 site and I'm experience a strange problem. I'm using the v5 HTML5 master page by Kyle Schaeffer (http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/v5-responsive-html5-master-page/). The site I'm working on has two master pages, one for the home page and one for the rest of the site. The only difference between the two is the home page master has a banner control that displays a rotating banner while the rest of the site which uses the second master page doesn't. The v5 master has a navigation menu on the left side of the master page. For the home page, this menu is hidden using CSS (the div that contains the menu has its display set to none) while the rest of the site has the menu active.

The top level site and sub sites have lists with pages in them and here is where my problem begins. If I create a page in the top level site, it will not show the the navigation menu on the left due to it being hidden by the top level master page. To counter this, I force the page layout of the page to use the secondary master page that the rest of the site uses (the secondary master page shows the left navigation menu). Despite using the secondary master page, it still doesn't show the navigation on the left side. Additionally, if I create a page from one of the sub sites that is using the secondary master page, it will show the left navigation menu just fine. Now am I missing something here or is the logic I'm attempting to use flawed? 
Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The pages always inherit the master from the parent site, if you want to have different master pages across your site you will have to create sites instead of pages, this way you will be able to change the master page on site settings under look and feel.